# Firebase Retrieve Limited Messages by Auto assigned timestamp

Tags: android, firebase

I wish to retrieve only the top 50 messages a user has within the database, with schema:

```
 "individualMessages" : {
    "99e4989b-a046-4c5f-9478-5ebd8bdc3ded" : {
      "a96da7b1-7c4e-44bc-b82e-fc75bed52bcd" : {
        "-KBUjngi9JStE-k4RMUJ" : {
          "from" : "a96da7b1-7c4e-44bc-b82e-fc75bed52bcd",
          "messageText" : "hey",
          "timeSent" : "2016-02-26 17:40:46"
        },
        "-KBYhsRONfGxVI7Ysb3F" : {
          "from" : "a96da7b1-7c4e-44bc-b82e-fc75bed52bcd",
          "messageText" : "pool",
          "timeSent" : "2016-02-27 12:10:52"
        }
      },
      "fdb17f3a-7b7d-4aa5-9a0b-b9fb33c349de" : {
        "-KBcYtQ5gD-drFZqz_MU" : {
          "from" : "fdb17f3a-7b7d-4aa5-9a0b-b9fb33c349de",
          "messageText" : "ouu",
          "timeSent" : "2016-02-28 10:46:52"
        },
        "-KBcYw24M-9-7H5A3czD" : {
          "from" : "fdb17f3a-7b7d-4aa5-9a0b-b9fb33c349de",
          "messageText" : "gsf",
          "timeSent" : "2016-02-28 10:47:03"
        }
```

However, simply using:

```
individualMessageMyPath = myFeastFirebase.child("individualMessages").child(.....

getTop50Messages = individualMessageMyPath.limitToLast(5);
getTop50Messages.orderByChild("timeSent").addChildEventListener(mainMessagingListener);
```

Returns all messages on that node.

Reviewing the documentation this should work, however it does not.

What is missing?

Comment: But most likely, it should be: `individualMessageMyPath.orderByChild("timeSent").limitToLast(5).addChildEventListener(...`. First you order, then you limit (based on that order). See  https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-complex-queries

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I followed the docs and altered to your note, yet still pulls all messages

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/bogufus/2/edit?html,js,output